# Average one field over two columns

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, group-by, average

I have searched around and have my own solution, but I believe there is a better way to achieve the result.

I have a dataframe with the following columns:

```
from_country   to_country    score
```

from_country and to_country columns have the same set of entries, e.g. US, UK, China, and so on. For each combination of from-to, there is a specific score.

I need to calculate the average of score for each country, regardless appearing in the from_country or the to_country field.

```
df_from = df[["from_country", "score"]].copy()
df_from.rename(columns={"from_country":"country"}, inplace=True)
df_to = df[["to_country", "score"]].copy()
df_to.rename(columns={"to_country":"country"}, inplace=True)
df_countries = pd.concat([df_from, df_to])
```

and then finally calculated the average over the new dataframe.

Is there a way to do it better?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can first `stack` the columns and then a simple `groupby` will get you all of the averages.

```
df.set_index('score').stack().reset_index().groupby(0).score.mean()
```

---

Here's an example, which renames the columns

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'from_country': ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'G'],
                   'to_country': ['G', 'C', 'Z', 'X', 'A', 'A'],
                   'score': [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]})

stacked = df.set_index('score').stack().to_frame('country').reset_index().drop(columns='level_1')
#    score country
#0       1       A
#1       1       G
#2       2       B
#3       2       C
#4       3       C
#5       3       Z
#...

stacked.groupby('country').score.mean()
```

Outputs:

```
country
A    4.0
B    2.0
C    2.5
D    4.0
E    5.0
G    3.5
X    4.0
Z    3.0
Name: score, dtype: float64
```

Answer (score 1):

Another way with `set_index` + `concat`:

```
pd.concat((
    df.set_index('from_country').score, 
    df.set_index('to_country').score
)).groupby(level=0).mean()

A    4.0
B    2.0
C    2.5
D    4.0
E    5.0
G    3.5
X    4.0
Z    3.0
```